# My AWS instances stuck on booting phase and fail with start_failed status.

Tags: amazon-web-services

instance stuck in booting phase and finally failed with status_failed. No chef logs available to debug. I ssh into instance, no logs available there either. pls. help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, there is not much information in your Question for people to assist you with possible Answers. Can you possibly provide more information? For example: How did you create the EC2 instance (or is it more than one instance)? Did it previously work? If so, what changed? If it is stuck in the booting phase, how are you able to `ssh` into it? Is this problem related to a Chef deployment? Please tell us more and we will be better able to offer you some potential Answers.

Comment: Sure. We have multiple instances setup and used to work fine. There is absolutely nothing changed in chef recipes(default or custom). The instances manage to boot and show online on ec2 console. But show status_failed on opsworks console. Looks like fail on setup phase. The main issue is there is no logs for chef deploy, so I can't figure out what happened during setup. I can ssh into instance as its online but setup is failed. How can it find the chef deploy logs. thanks for help

Comment: @JohnRotenstein. It looks like the the instances are failing while the build on recipes running on the instance. These build on recipes are from aws. Here is the list of recepes for setup. opsworks_initial_setup, ssh_host_keys, ssh_users, mysql::clientdependencies, ebsopsworks_ganglia::client. Pls. suggest how to debug this.

Comment: the only log i have is user-data.log for opsworks:Sun, 08 May 2016 orks-init: Finished: Unpack Agent Package in 0 sec.


[Sun, 08 May 2016 20:56:23 +0000] installer-wrapper: Using opsworks-instance-assets-eu-west-1.s3.amazonaws.com for assets.
[Sun, 08 May 2016 20:56:23 +0000] installer-wrapper: Skipping installation of opsworks-agent-ruby because it's already installed
[Sun, 08 May 2016 20:56:23 +0000] installer-wrapper: Installing instance agent
/tmp/opsworks-agent-installer/opsworks-agent/bin/installer_wrapper.sh: line 203: /opt/aws/opsworks/local/bin/ruby: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a similar problem and have found that it may be an issue with the AWS OpsWorks agent. I was able to resolve the issue by downgrading the OpsWorks Agent version when launching an instance:

[image: Change OpsWorks Version]

It is not 100% clear why, but there appears to be a miscommunication between the ubuntu apt package for opsworks and the latest version of the OpsWorks agent setup script.

Comment: I have already fixed the issue. You are right. It was due to auto upgrade of opsworks agent which was not compatible with ruby version.